# Can't access Action Bar item view programatically - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view

My code (in `onCreate()` method:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.main_action_bar, null);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);

    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) v.findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
```

Then when I try to programatically change the view using:

```
profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
```

I get error "Can't call `setProfileId` on `null` reference.

How should I properly access ths view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for a check if you don't mind can you do that for me and tell me whether it works or not.

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   //simply use getSupportActionBar() and check
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.main_action_bar, null);

   profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) v.findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);

   profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);

  // declaring it here because you are setting the whole view in the actionbar now after adding the profile pic and all. So may it is a reason it is not been able to find out the actionbar to be applied on
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
}
```

Comment: @DennisCallanan Could you please mark this answer right and upvote it if it helped you anyway. Thanks.

Comment: It seemed to have worked.. now it spontaneously stopped working again !!

Comment: @DennisCallanan what is the error you are getting now?

Comment: Nevermind, different error now, this solution worked !!

Comment: Thanks a lot @DennisCallanan. Happy to help you.